# Modal on Modal with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I need to open a modal on another modal, the problem is that the first modal loses the scrool bar of the main page after closing the modal that is on it.

I'll try to explain better:

I have this modal which loads in the modal-body a content that can be extensive coming from a query in Ajax

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Concluir </h4>
           </div>
          <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body"></div>                                
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I load the information to be displayed in the modal-body  in the following Jquery action:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn_open_modal1', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();        
     $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "load.php",
        data: {id : id},
        async: false,
        dataType: "text",     
        success: function(data){           
            $('#modal-body').html(data);
            $('#modal_1').modal('show');   
        }
      })
})
```

In this modal that will open has a button to call another modal

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="confirm">Confirm</button>
```

In this modal that will open has a button to call another modal
clicking this button launches a new Ajax call to open a new modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_2">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header text-white bg-dark">Confirm: </div>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-no" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            <a class="btn btn-primary text-white btn-yes" id="btn-yes">Yes</a>

       </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '#confirm', function(event){ 
event.preventDefault();                             
    $("#modal_2").modal().find("#btn-yes").off('click').on("click", function(event){ 
           event.preventDefault();                    
                 $.ajax ({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: "update.php",
                      data: {id : id},                 
                      dataType: "text",     
                      success: function(data){ 
                                $('#modal_2').modal('hide');                                                      
                            }
                 })   
         })    
    })
```

In this modal that will open has a button to call another modal
clicking this button launches a new Ajax call to open a new modal.
When I close modal_2, modal_1 loses scrool and it is no longer possible to scroll the page.
I skidded a lot about Modal over Modal, but I did not find anything that uses Jquery (Ajax) and that the modal content is large enough to scroll the page and that it is influenced by the modal upper

Answer (score 0):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/2q6mp1    You can do this in PHP.

This is what your view will look like.  I am adding a .NET Fiddle link above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut139</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btn_open_modal1").click(function () {
                $('#exampleModal').modal('show');

            })

            $("#btn_open_modal2").click(function () {
                $('#exampleModa2l').modal('show');

            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button id="btn_open_modal1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch outer modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div style="height:50px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                        ...
                        does not lose its scroll
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
                        remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
                        sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                        Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
                        remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
                        sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                        Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
                        remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
                        sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                        Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="btn_open_modal2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
                        Launch second modal
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                    Close this second modal and first modal, still has scroll capabilities
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi kblau, thanks for answer.
In sample that you showed me, is happending the same problem, look in https://dotnetfiddle.net/2q6mp1.
It´s showed the first modal and your scrool, perfect, after to click in 'Lauch Second Modal' is showed the second modal and your scrool is ok too. When I close the second modal, look for the first modal scrool, it disappers. this is the that happens im my application and is wrong. The scrool of first modal should to appear after close the second modal.

Comment: @RafaelChristófano Hi.  I tried the link in IE 11, Edge, Chrome, and Firefox.  They all worked- first modal has scroll, call second modal to come up.  Clicked on close, now first modal still has scroll.  Is there something unique with your browser?  Can you try it out on someone else's browser or at home?

Comment: Did you not understand. I don´t want the scroll that´s on inside the  <div class="modal-body">, I want the scroll that´s on the main page, out-side of the modal.

Comment: Ok.  Sorry about that.  I will see if I can come up with anything.